# Definition of angular velocity in rotational motion of a non-rigid body?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, definition, angular-velocity

Consider a particle in rotational motion with radius ***r*** and angular velocity *w* both varying with time, what is the relationship between the displacement ***u*** and w of the particle? $w=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}*\frac{1}{r}$, $w=\frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial t}*\frac{1}{r}$ or $\textbf{w}=w\textbf{e}_{z}=\frac{\textbf{r}\times \textbf{v}}{{\left|\textbf{r}\right|}^2}=\frac{\textbf{r}}{{\left|\textbf{r}\right|}^2}\times\frac{\partial \textbf{u}}{\partial t}$ ? where $u$ represents the magnitude of ***u***, $u_{\theta}$ is the component of ***u*** in $\theta$ direction and $r$ is the magnitude of ***r***. For simplicity, the rotational motion is in the xy plane and the angular velocity is along the z direction.

Comment: My friend suggested that the relationship between moment of inertia and angular momentum could be used to solve this problem.